# Show that $W$ and $W'$ are subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

1. Determine if $W=\{A\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}: A^2=A\}$ is a subspace of $V=\Bbb R^{n\times n}$.
2. Let $ B $ be a fixed matrix of $n\times n$ and consider the set $W'=\{A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}: AB=BA\}$. Is $W' $ a subspace of $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$?

**My try:**  To show that W is a subspace of V, we must show that three conditions are met, that the null matrix belongs, that it is closed under the sum and under the scalar product.  For the second, I fix matrix $ B $ and consider $ A, A '\in W' $, this is $ AB = BA $ and $ A'B = BA '$.  Then, adding member to member, we have to,
$$AB+A'B=BA+BA'\Rightarrow (A+A')B=B(A+A').$$
That is, $A+A'\in W'$.

Btw, it's clear that the matrix $0$ fulfills that, since $0\cdot B = B\cdot 0$ for any matrix $B$.

Finally, let $ k \in \Bbb R $ and $ A \in W '$.  Then,
$$\begin{align*}(kA)B&=k(AB)\\ &=k(BA)\\ &=(kB)A\\&=(Bk)A\\ &=B(kA).  \end{align*}$$
That is, $kA\in W'$. This shows that $ W '$ is a subspace of $ V $.

For the first I think that the sum is not fulfilled, some help.  And my proof of the second is correct?

Comment: For the first part, note that $I \in W$, but $2I \not\in W$. Your solution for the second part looks OK to me.

Comment: Ty so much, Bungo. I appreciated. :)